# Tricky AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a client ( written in JS-jQuery ) sending 4 requests to a server ( written in ASP.NET-C# ).
The first 3 requests work fine; but the last one is empty when received server side.

1. When i use firebug to see the request sent by the client, it looks fine, but the server still receive an empty QueryString;
2. When i do a "Step by step" debugging with firebug, the server gets the correct request.

I thought it was a Cross Domain problem, but in that case all the 4 requests should not work !!
Have you ever had a similar problem ? How can i solve this problem ?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sounds like a "synchronisity" issue - have you tried setting async=false on your ajaxSetup ?

Comment: show the code that makes the requests

Answer (score 0):

Setting `async: false` has other implications.

If you set `async` to false the browser will bet blocked till the response comes back to the client from the server, this will impact the client performance and user experience. If you can share the piece of code which is causing the problem we may be able to help you to solve it. Setting `async` to false may not be the right solution.

Can you share some details regarding the following points
What is the order in which the requests are made?
Is all request independent or some requests are depending on other requests response value?

The chances of the 4th ajax request(the one which fails) depending on another request(1 of the first 3) is very much because you are saying if you set the `async` to `false` the request is working fine.

In this case I would suggest something like

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'request whose result need to be used in the 4th request',
    data:{....}
    ....
}).success(function(result){
    $.ajax({
        url : '4ht request',
        data:{
            xyx : result.abc,
            ......
        }
    });
})
```